# .net Enumerable.Sum() is not responding when trying to find the sum of more than 70000 items

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, foreach, sum

I was testing a case scenario where I tried to find out the difference between the time taken to calculate the sum of a integer List using

1. traditional foreach loop and,
2. Enumerable.Sum()

The foreach loop was quicker but that's not issue. When I tried to find the sum of more than 70000 items, the foreach loop was functioning as expected however, the code was not getting executed after the Sum!! I have no idea why this is happening. Below is the code that I was using for the test case.

```
        List<int> lstInt = GetIntValues();

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (int i in lstInt)
        {
            counter += i;
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        lblText.Text = String.Concat("Time elapsed after for-each ", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        counter = 0;

        stopWatch.Restart();
        counter = lstInt.Sum();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        lblText.Text = String.Concat(lblText.Text, " Time elapsed after linq ", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Plz explain this anomaly.

EDIT::
OK here are some stats

**With int variable:**

- ForEach value of the counter is -1845002296 [wrong]
- Sum() is throwing the error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

**with long variable:**

- ForEach value of the counter is 2449965000 [correct]
- Sum() is still throwing the same error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Comment: where is your foreach loop?

Comment: So 69999 items "works", but 70000 doesn't?

Comment: I guess it was elided for the example, because just timing `int count = 0` doesn't seem like a very useful piece of code to time :)

What is the question, does the sum not execute, or does the code never reach the code _after_ that?

Comment: @LolCoder I have added the foreach loop now. Actually I had removed it since the code was not working.

Comment: @user2864740 it was working with 60,000 items. I then increased the items to 70,000 and then nothings happening.

Comment: @CompuChip the question is that the code never reach the code after the Sum().

Comment: Try adding a `try ... catch` block to check if an Exception is being thrown.

Comment: Yes, I got the error, **Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.** exception in the try catch block!!!   @CompuChip

Comment: @Piyush : Your total sum value exceeds maximum value of int32. Use long integer for assigning the value of Sum()

Comment: OK, that seems like a clear error. I am wondering now though, why your first approach works, because there you are also storing the result in an integer.

Comment: OK here are some stats
_With int variable:_
ForEach value of the counter is -1845002296 [wrong]
Sum() is throwing the error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

_with long variable:_
ForEach value of the counter is 2449965000 [correct]
Sum() is still throwing the same error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

@LolCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the foreach version of the code will also throw the same error as the Enumerable.Sum() if inside the foreach loop, I replace,

```
counter += i;
```

to

```
counter = checked(counter + i);
```

provided the counter variable is of type Int32.

The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions. [More Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

Secondly, I was getting the same error for the Enumerable.Sum() even if I change the counter from int to long. This is because of the fact that the List on which the Sum operation was being carried out was of type Int32!

So, when I changed,

```
counter = lstInt.Sum();
```

to

```
counter = list.Select(i => (long)i).Sum();
```

the error was gone.

In short, the whole issue was because of the fact that the total sum value [*assigned to the counter variable*] exceeded the maximum value of Int32.